# Best quicker faster acceleration NGK spark plugs

Tags: toyota, sparkplugs, performance

What kind of NGK spark plug can I use on my 1990 Toyota Conquest 2E for quicker start and for faster acceleration?

Answer (score 4):

Faster starts and quicker acceleration require more torque. I suppose spark plugs might make some difference there, but I don't think you'll see a significant change if the engine is reasonably well tuned.

This is what [NGK has to say](https://www.ngksparkplugs.com/about-ngk/faqs/spark-plug-faqs/how-much-of-a-performance-improvement-can-i-expect-from-changing-plugs) on the question - basically don't expect much, if anything (maybe 1-2% if you're replacing badly worn plugs).